# How can I make this conditional riddled instance method more Ruby idiomatic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, idioms, instance-method

```
  def short_remaining_time
    difference  = Time.diff(Time.now, created_at + 7.days, '%d - %H - %N')

    # To display the short remaining time in an auction listing.
    if difference[:day] == 0 and difference[:hour] >= 1
      "#{difference[:minute]} minutos"
    elsif difference[:day] == 0 and difference[:hour] >= 23
      "#{difference[:hour]} horas"
    else
      if difference[:day] != 1
        "#{difference[:day]} dias"
      else
        "#{difference[:day]} dia"
      end
    end
  end
```

This method is inside my `auction.rb` model in my Rails application.

In one of my views, I am listing all auctions in the system, and I also display how much time is remaining before the auction closes.

Depending on the amount of time, I either show the `days` `hours` or `minutes`.

The code is working fine, just looks and feels very clunky. Is there a way to spruce this up a bit?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it as below. Note that your code is redundant. If `difference[:hour] >= 23`, then that entails `difference[:hour] >= 1`, and will be captured by the latter, so the former condition will never be evaluated to true. So that part can be removed.

```
def short_remaining_time
  difference  = Time.diff(Time.now, created_at + 7.days, '%d - %H - %N')
  case day = difference[:day]
  when 0
    if difference[:hour] >= 1 then "#{difference[:minute]} minutos"
    else "#{day} dias"
    end
  when 1 then "#{day} dia"
  else "#{day} dias"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you got your inequalities unintentionally not quite right (you need `<=` not `>=`). Also, if you assume that the hours in the difference will always be no more than `23`, you don't need that check (i.e., we're assuming the time difference is "normalized"). So I'd modify it this way to keep your original intent:

```
  def short_remaining_time
    difference  = Time.diff(Time.now, created_at + 7.days, '%d - %H - %N')

    # To display the short remaining time in an auction listing.
    if difference[:day] == 0
      if difference[:hour] <= 1
        "#{difference[:minute]} minutos"
      else
        "#{difference[:hour]} horas"
      end
    else
      "#{difference[:day]} dia" + ((difference[:day] == 1) ? "" : "s")
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `no implicit conversion of nil into String`. It's trying to convert `nil` into a string if `difference[:day]` is not 1.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
def short_remaining_time
  difference      = Time.diff(Time.now, created_at + 7.days, '%d - %H - %N')
  diff_in_minutes = difference[:day] * 3600 + difference[:hour] * 60

  case diff_in_minutes
    when 0..60      then  "#{difference[:minute]} minutos"
    when 61..3600   then  "#{difference[:hour]  } horas"
    when 3600..7200 then  "#{difference[:day]   } dia"
    else                  "#{difference[:day]   } dias"
  end
end
```